# ConcurrentBag issue when bag is null and instantiated in loop

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Please give me a hint about the following issue:

```
ConcurrentBag<string> test = null;
List<string> list= new() { "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2",
    "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3" };
Parallel.ForEach(list, x => { (test ??= new()).Add("result"); });
```

=> test will have a different value each time when debugging (e. g. 19 / 23 entries)

```
ConcurrentBag<string> test = new();
List<string> list= new() { "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2",
    "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3" };
Parallel.ForEach(list, x => { (test ??= new()).Add("result"); });
```

=> test will always have 23 entries

Why does the `Parallel.ForEach` not properly add the values when it's instantiated with `null`?

Comment: Since it's running in parallel, some threads are encountering a `null` and re-instantiating the `ConcurrentBag` and adding it's value, thus it gets overwritten and in some cases you get less than 23 entries. Hence, when you set it to `new`, each thread doesn't encounter `null` and adds its value giving you the expected result.

Comment: What you are experiencing is often referred to as a "race condition" - [what-is-a-race-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition#:~:text=A%20race%20condition%20occurs%20when,to%20access%20the%20shared%20data.)

Comment: @RyanWilson ty, was already guessing something like that

Comment: No problem. Glad that helped clear it up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test ??= new()
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
if (test == null)
    test = new();
```

You are using multiple threads, so consider this scenario:

1. Thread 1 reaches the `if` and sees that `test` is null. It therefore is about to go on to the next line, when it is pre-empted by thread 2
2. Thread 2 reaches the `if` and sees that `test` is null. It therefore
   is goes on to create a new `ConcurrentBag` and assign it to `test`.
3. Thread 1 now continues and creates a new `ConcurrentBag` and assigns it to `test`, overwriting the one created by thread 2.

Now you have two instances of `ConcurrentBag` in use, but only one is assigned to `test`.